# Using custom component in ag-grid cell render

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am trying to use a custom component in a cell in ag-grid, if i use a standard html component it works but not if i try to use a custom react component

Below code does not works

```
TABLE_COLUMNS = [
        {
            headerName: '', field: 'remarks', cellRendererFramework: (params) => {
                return <div>
                    <SpinningWheel height={100}/>
                </div>
            }
        }]
```

But below code works fine

```
TABLE_COLUMNS = [
        {
            headerName: '', field: 'remarks', cellRendererFramework: (params) => {
                return <div>
                    <button>push me</button>
                </div>
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working fine for me. I have created a similar component wrapped inside a div in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pVW2rRs08R6RQWKl7ShO?p=preview) from one of their examples and it is working as expected. Look for the following in `columnDefs` in index.js file.

```
{
    headerName: "Child/Parent",
    field: "value",
    cellRendererFramework: (params) => <div><SpinningWheel {...params} name="Spinning Wheel"/></div>,
    colId: "params",
    width: 180
 }
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with my css, when i disable the background-size property via chrome dev tools, i can see the spinning wheel. Unfortunately the code for SpinningWheel is not in my control, will have to look how to make the component visible

Comment: There are many ways to manipulate css even if the component code is not acessible. Where is this background-size applied? On the grid or on the Spinning Wheel component. Can you provide more detail?